# Expectation: E(X-Y) and Variance: Var(X-Y) in statistics

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation, covariance

There are $n$ students and you pick a student replacement so each pick is independent . $p$ is the portion of the student body that will vote for A instead of B for student council president.

Let $X = # of the students who'll vote for A in n$

Let $Y = # of students who'll vote for B$

1. $E(X-Y)$
2. $Var(X-Y)$

Express X in terms of Y

How do I approach this?
From definition, I'm assuming:$$E(X) = \sum_{n=0}^{pn}aP(X=a)$$
Which means $$E(Y) = \sum_{n=0}^{(1-p)n}bP(Y=b)$$

And since $E(X-Y) = E(X)-E(Y)$, I subtract one from the other.
Here I get stuck...but I know if I can solve for $E(X)$ and $E(Y)$, I can find $Var(X-Y)$

Comment: Wouldn't $E(X)=pn$ and $E(Y)=(1-p)n$ for $n$ students?

Comment: Yes, Silynn, those are the correct expectations for $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We assume that there are only two candidates. Then $Y=n-X$, so $X-Y=2X-n$.

The expectation of $2X-n$ is $2E(X)-E(n)$. We have $E(n)=n$. The random variable $X$ has Binomial distribution, parameters $n$ and $p$, so $E(X)=np$.

Thus $E(X-Y)=2np-n$.

For the variance of $X-Y$, we want $\text{Var}(2X-n)$. This is $2^2\text{Var}(X)$.

The variance of $X$ is $np(1-p)$, by standard information about the Binomial. Thus $X-Y$ has variance $4np(1-p)$.

Comment: I see! 
But can you please explain how $Var(2X-n) = 2^2Var(X)$? 
Is this a property of variance?

Comment: Yes. In general if $a$ and $b$ are constants, then $\text{Var}(aX+b)=a^2\text{Var}(X)$. Note that the variance of a random variable measures its "wiggliness." The random variable $aX+b$ has the same wiggliness as $aX$.

Comment: Can we maybe use the term "spread" instead of "wiggliness"? I think people would understand it a little better if we related SD and variance to how spread out numbers are.

Comment: I agree that spread might be a better term, the only thing that makes me nervous is that a distribution highly concentrated at $0$ with a sharply decaying long tail might be viewed as having large spread.